# Connecting and Testing Memcached with PHP

Tags: php, memcached

after spending some time trying to setup Memcached on MAMP I can came into a bit of a pickle...

On my php info file it states memcached and displays the relevant information:
[image: Image of php info file]

In order to learn and use Memcached I was using the following tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/faster-php-mysql-websites-in-minutes/?search_index=1

This is where I encountered my first issue, this being connecting to the Cache Server: by using what they had stated, did not seem to work.

```
define('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('MEMCACHED_PORT', '11211');
$memcache = new Memcache;
$cacheAvailable = $memcache->connect(MEMCACHED_HOST, MEMCACHED_PORT);
```

I tried changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost, this did not work. My first point of call was to change memcache to memcached... This still did not work.

Therefore I just want to clear up how to connect and test a connection has been made with Memcached. If there is in fact a different connection between Memcache and Memcached? Or maybe I have set something up wrong? Any advice or guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: Short answer: The MemcacheD deamon has to be running, just installing the module into PHP is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the reason as to why I could not connect to Memcached and thought I would post the answer just incase anyone had the same issue I had.

To solution was to type the following in Terminal:

```
memcached -d
```

As I figured out it seems memcached effectively needs to be switched on. The above code did that. Although every-time your restart your machine you will have to do what I just stated. Im still looking for a answer that auto starts memcached. If i come across it I shall update this article.

Comment: Just for those seeing this and looking to auto start it you need to add it to `/etc/init.d/memcached`

Answer (score 4):

First things first I suppose you should attempt to connect with telnet to memcahed.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Here is some documentation on supported commands assuming you are able to connect: http://lzone.de/articles/memcached.htm

If you can't telnet to it then your setup is bad or you might have some firewall blocking it.

There are two clients for PHP, [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.addserver.php).  I would recommend using memcached (I have no idea why they named the client like it were a daemon - drives me nuts).  The newer memcached client supports CAS operations and some other newer features.

The connection code you are using though looks more like memcache.  With memcached you will want to set up a server pool or just use [`addServer()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.addserver.php).

Comment: thankyou @ficuscr for your reply, would this mean a connection would be $m = new Memcached(); $m->addServer(telnet,'localhost', 11211); ? Im still a bit puzzled, as it seems all the tutorials of how-toos are in regards to memcache... for example http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/using-memcache-with-mysql-and-php/ Appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes and yeah, most tutorials will probably talk about the older memcache client.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926376/memcache-connect-vs-addserver It is really not that different.  Would be easy to abstract code jsut a bit and use either client.  Anyway it is all documented: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php  Just have to know which one is which :)

Comment: When I did the $m = new Memcached(); $m->addServer(telnet,'localhost', 11211); gave me the error of Warning: Memcached::addServer() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/mem.php on line 5... So frustrating. Id there anyway I can just use Memcache even though I have Memcached installed?

Comment: `telnet` is a tool, I was suggesting using it to ensure the memcahced service is running and reachable.  You just want: $m->addServer('localhost', 11211);  [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.addserver.php)  Use what you want, already made my suggestions.

Comment: I believe telnet is for a Windows environment, I probably should have stated im using a Mac. I have had a look at the manual... I tried the following code just to test if everything is working, but for some reason nothing is echoed out... Its just a blank page :-S $mc = new Memcached(); 
$mc->addServer("localhost", 11211); 
$mc->set("foo", "Hello World");
echo $mc->get("foo");

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/telnet.1.html